# how to use routes with controller and without controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have multi controller and Area in website. I want use url without controller for default controller name. so use this coded for route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "WithOutController",
           url: "{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

This working. But working for all controller, not only default controller. I also tried this code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "WithOutController",
           url: "{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
```

But this code working only url with controller. I want it to work this way:

- Default/Index: url(http://localhost:2470/Index)
- Default/Login: url(http://localhost:2470/Login)
- Panel/Index: url(http://localhost:2470/Panel/Index)

Answer (score 0):

No sure how many actions your default controller need to be mapped to a URL without the **default** name on it. But if it is only two you can try this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultIndex",
            url: "Index/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultLogin",
            url: "Login/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Another option is to enable **MapMvcAttributeRoutes** and decorate your actions with the desired routes.

To enable **MapMvcAttributeRoutes**:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Then in your default controller you need to:

```
[Route("Index")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("Login")]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

Your default action name MUST be something different to the Route Attributes names.

Comment: My default controller has several actions. And that may not be the right solution for me. Is there no other solution?

Comment: I just updated the answer with another option.